# Real topological K-theory of cyclic group

Tags: representation-theory, topological-k-theory, k-theory

Letting $C_n$ be the cyclic group on $n$ elements we know through the use of the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem that
$$
K^*(BG) = \pi_*(KU)[[t]]/((t+1)^n -1)
$$
where $\pi_*(KU)=\mathbb{Z}[u^{\pm 1}]$ with $u$ being the Bott periodicity element in $\pi_2(KU)$. I was wondering if it was possible to do something similar to caluclate real $K$-theory $KO^*(BC_n)$ for cyclic groups of odd order. We can for example use the real representation ring to caluclate
$$ 
KO^0(BG) = \mathbb{Z}[[t]]/(tf_n(t))
$$
with $f_n(t)$ being some complicated polynomial, but is it necessarily true that
$$
KO^*(BG) = \pi_*(KO)[[t]]/(tf_n(t)) 
$$
holds?